# PHP: Checking request referrer for URL params

Tags: php, laravel

I am a Ruby dev. but doing some patch work on PHP and still learning the ropes.
There is a function I have that used to check the URL params inside the Account function by calling: `$request->has("PARAM HERE")`

However, I need to check the URL params from inside a different function, storeCart, now which doesn't have direct access to access to the request params but when looking at the request info, I can see it has the url with the params inside the "referrer" part of the request.  How can I use this to accomplish checking against the param?

Comment: _“I can see it has the url with the params inside the "referrer" part of the request”_ - it might for you - but it probably won’t, for a lot of users, that use privacy-enhancing extensions that block sending of a referrer. You can not _rely_ on the referrer, ever. If you use it to extract information that are vital for your app functioning properly - then you are Doing. Things. Wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get variables from the HTTP_REFERER, you will need to extract and parse them yourself.

```php
// isolate the query part of the referer URL
$qString = explode('?', Request::server('HTTP_REFERER'))[1] ?? null;

// decode and store into $myParams
$myParams = [];
parse_str($qString, $myParams);

// check for existing param
if(isset($myParams['my_param'])) {
    // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: hmm, so my url is /account?orderNum=44 and I am logging: `request()->has('orderNum')` and it's coming back as false

Comment: I'd need to see your code to know why that's happening. For me, if I go to `/home?stuff=things`, then `request()->has('stuff')` returns true, and `request('stuff')` returns 'things'. Could you add some code to your question?

Comment: When I go to log the `request()->url()`, it's showing `/orderCart` because it's the orderCart function...but the actual URL in the browser is `'/account?orderNum`

Comment: Are you running an API call from `/account` that then calls `/orderCart`?

Comment: yep, exactly @newUserName02